# Designing a generic hash

Tags: c, generics, hash

I am trying to implement a generic hash structure that can support any type of data and any hash function.

A wrote the code and try to run it, it dosn't work, it breaks. I try to debug it and there it works well. I don't know where the problem is?

Here is the code that I used for implementing the structure:

The "hash.h" file:

```
typedef struct tip_hash_nod
{
    void *info;
    struct tip_hash_nod *urm;
}NOD_LISTA_HASH;

typedef struct
{
    NOD_LISTA_HASH *Table;
    int size;
    int sizeMemory;
    int (*hash)(const void *obiect,const int m);
    void (*distruge)(void *obiect);
}*HASH;

void initializare_hash(HASH *h,int size,int (*hash_dat)(const void *obiect,const int m),void (*distruge)(void *obiect));
int hash_insert(HASH *h,void *obiect,int sizeOfObiect);
int hash_search(HASH h,void *obiect,int (*compara)(const void *a,const void *b));
void hash_delete(HASH *h);
```

And the "hash.c" file:

```
void initializare_hash(HASH *h,int size,int (*hash_dat)(const void *obiect,const int m),void (*distruge)(void *obiect))
{
    int i;
    (*h) = (HASH)malloc(sizeof(HASH));
    (*h)->sizeMemory = size;
    if(size != 0)
    {
        (*h)->Table = (NOD_LISTA_HASH *)malloc((*h)->sizeMemory * sizeof(NOD_LISTA_HASH));
        for(i=0;i<(*h)->sizeMemory;i++)
        {
            (*h)->Table[i].info = NULL;
            (*h)->Table[0].urm = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        (*h)->Table = (NOD_LISTA_HASH *)malloc(sizeof(NOD_LISTA_HASH));
        (*h)->Table[0].info = NULL;
        (*h)->Table[0].urm = NULL;
        (*h)->sizeMemory = 1;
    }
    (*h)->size = 0;
    (*h)->hash = hash_dat;
    (*h)->distruge = distruge;
}
int hash_insert(HASH *h,void *obiect,int sizeOfObiect)
{
    int i,poz;
    NOD_LISTA_HASH *p;
    if((*h)->size == (*h)->sizeMemory)
    {
        HASH h1;
        initializare_hash(&h1,2*(*h)->sizeMemory,(*h)->hash,(*h)->distruge);
        for(i=0;i<(*h)->sizeMemory;i++)
        {
            if((*h)->Table[i].info != NULL)
                hash_insert(&h1,(*h)->Table[i].info,sizeOfObiect);
            p=(*h)->Table[i].urm;
            while(p!=NULL)
            {
                hash_insert(&h1,p->info,sizeOfObiect);
                p = p->urm;
            }
        }
        hash_delete(h);
        *h=h1;
        return hash_insert(h,obiect,sizeOfObiect);
    }
    else
    {
        poz = (*h)->hash(obiect,(*h)->sizeMemory);
        if((*h)->Table[poz].info == NULL)
        {
            (*h)->Table[poz].info = malloc(sizeOfObiect);
            memcpy((*h)->Table[poz].info,obiect,sizeOfObiect);
            (*h)->Table[poz].urm = NULL;
            (*h)->size++;
        }
        else
        {
            p = &((*h)->Table[poz]);
            while(p->urm!=NULL)
                p = p->urm;
            p->urm = (NOD_LISTA_HASH *)malloc(sizeof(NOD_LISTA_HASH));
            p = p->urm;
            p->info = malloc(sizeOfObiect);
            memcpy(p->info,obiect,sizeOfObiect);
            p->urm = NULL;
        }
        return poz;
    }
}

int hash_search(HASH h,void *obiect,int (*compara)(const void *a,const void *b))
{
    int poz;
    NOD_LISTA_HASH *p;
    poz = h->hash(obiect,h->sizeMemory);
    if(h->Table[poz].info == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        if(compara(h->Table[poz].info,obiect)==0)
            return poz;
        else
        {
            p=h->Table[poz].urm;
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                if(compara(p->info,obiect)==0)
                    return poz;
                p = p->urm;
            }
            return -1;
        }
}

static void distruge_lista(NOD_LISTA_HASH *p,void (*distruge_obiect)(void *obiect))
{
    if(p->urm != NULL)
        distruge_lista(p->urm,distruge_obiect);
    else
    {
        if(p->info != NULL)
            distruge_obiect(p->info);
        free(p);
    }
}

void hash_delete(HASH *h)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(*h)->sizeMemory;i++)
    {
        if((*h)->Table[i].info != NULL && (*h)->Table[i].urm != NULL)
        {
            distruge_lista((*h)->Table[i].urm,(*h)->distruge);
        }
    }
    free((*h)->Table);
    *h = NULL;
}
```

And this is my "main.c" file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "hash.h"

int comparare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

int hash(const void *obiect,int m)
{
    return (*(int *)obiect) % m;
}

void distruge_obiect(void *obiect)
{
    free((int *)obiect);
}

int main()
{
    HASH h;
    int val,error;

    initializare_hash(&h,0,hash,distruge_obiect);

    val = 20;
    hash_insert(&h,&val,sizeof(int));
    val = 800;
    hash_insert(&h,&val,sizeof(int));
    val = 2000;
    hash_insert(&h,&val,sizeof(int));
    val = 765;
    hash_insert(&h,&val,sizeof(int));

    val = 800;
    error = hash_search(h,&val,comparare);
    if(error == -1)
        printf("Elementul %d nu se afla in hash.\n",val);
    else
        printf("Elementul %d se afla pe pozitia: %d.\n",val,error);
    hash_delete(&h);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

How I already sad if I try to debug it works with no problem, but when I run it, it crashes. I can onely make an assumption that it can not dealocate the memory or something. My call stack loocks like this:
[image: call stack]

Comment: To narrow down the search for runtime issues I like to have subroutines return info on whether or not they succeeded, or how many iterations they have gone through.  It may help.

Comment: @RoddeyFrost it is after the second insertion that it crashing. It is the point where it has to replace the hash structure with one twice as big

Comment: If you're trying to build this for the experience, then great, carry on.  But if you're doing it mainly because you want to *use* it, then you should consider an existing tried and true implementation such as [UTHash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/).

Comment: One more example of why it is error prone to use typedef'd pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've dropped a pretty big pile of code on us, without much to go on.  I had a quick look anyway, and noticed this incorrect allocation:

```
(*h) = (HASH)malloc(sizeof(HASH));
```

`HASH` is a pointer type, so you are allocating only enough memory for one pointer.  You want to allocate memory for the thing to which it points:

```
*h = malloc(sizeof(**h));
```

(The cast is not required in C, and some folks around here will be strident about not using one.)

That error would be entirely enough to cause all manner of bad behavior.  In particular, the erroneous code might seem to work until you dynamically allocate more memory and write to that, so perhaps that explains why your tests crash on the second insertion.